# isAuthenticated is always null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

**isAuthenticated is always null**

I am trying to compare token expired or not but isAuthenticated is always null

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

interface IPrivateRoute {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

const PrivateRoute = ({children}: IPrivateRoute) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean | null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        if (token) {
            let decodedToken:number = jwtDecode<any>(token).exp;
            let date:number = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
            console.log(decodedToken <= date)
            if (decodedToken <= date) {
                setIsAuthenticated(true)
            } else {
                setIsAuthenticated(false)
            }
        } else {
            setIsAuthenticated(false)
        }
    })

    return (
        <>
            {isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to='/login'/>}
        </>
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: I think you have a problem in your date checking and maybe you confused between seconds and milliseconds

Comment: Does `console.log(decodedToken <= date)` print a Boolean?

Comment: @PierreJanineh, yes

Comment: You probably just need to add semicolons at then end of every line.

Comment: @PierreJanineh, I don't think it will help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that `isAuthenticated` ***IS*** `null` on the initial render, which is a falsey value, and the navigation to `"/login"` occurs, unmounting this `PrivateRoute` wrapper component. The `useEffect` never gets to update the state to anything meaningful while the component is still mounted.

You've likely a couple options:

1. Conditionally render nothing (*or loading indicator, etc...*) while the `isAuthenticated` state is settled ***then*** conditionally render `children` or `Navigate`.

   ```
   const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: IPrivateRoute) => {
     const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

     useEffect(() => {
       const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
       if (token) {
         const decodedToken: number = jwtDecode<any>(token).exp;
         const date: number = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

         setIsAuthenticated(decodedToken <= date);
       } else {
         setIsAuthenticated(false);
       }
     });

     if (isAuthenticated === null) return null;

     return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
   };
   ```
2. Provide a state initializer function to provide the valid boolean `true`|`false` `isAuthenticated` value you are looking for on the initial render.

   ```
   const initializeState = () => {
     const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
     if (token) {
       const decodedToken: number = jwtDecode<any>(token).exp;
       const date: number = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

       return decodedToken <= date;
     }
     return false;
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: IPrivateRoute) => {
     const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(initializeState);

     useEffect(() => {
       const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
       if (token) {
         const decodedToken: number = jwtDecode<any>(token).exp;
         const date: number = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

         setIsAuthenticated(decodedToken <= date);
       } else {
         setIsAuthenticated(false);
       }
     });

     return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
   };
   ```